# Poor image quality rendering UIImage with opengl on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm using [this](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m) code to render some UIImages in a cover flow on the ipad. The problem is the images are kind of blurry. I've been reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html) to attempt to decipher the opengl code and figure out what the problem might be. This link also speaks of "multisampling" to improve image quality. The problem is I don't know if there might be some other obvious issue. Is it normal to have some blurring when rendering png's with opengl? Not knowing opengl, it would take some time to try the multisampling to improve this, so I'd like to know if that's the right direction to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic suggestion that can be given with OpenGL textures is making your image resolution in a power of 2's.

Of course this is very generic, since we have no info about your image, but it is what I would try before going for multisampling, which certainly improve rendering.

Comment: yea, lack of knowledge, but this high level info was all I was after for now (haven't had time to test this, but I'm accepting the answer, as it's perfectly logical.